# Custom train_step with combination of losses and regularization loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need to use a custom `train_step`  in my `model.fit`  of Tensorflow to use a linear combination of two losses as loss function, i.e. cross-entropy (as usual in supervised classification tasks) and another loss which may be anything -- not really important for my question. In addition, I would like to still use the `regularization_loss`  that I defined in my model layers (e.g.,  `L2 regularization` ). I wonder if the following code correctly implements what I would like to do.

In particular, since L2 regularization adds a penalty to the loss (so in this case `ce_loss` should already comprise the L2 regularization term), I think that it is correct to then just add the `additional_loss` to the `ce_loss`. Is this correct?

```
import tensorflow as tf


class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, model):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
        self.model = model

    def compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, another_loss, gamma=0.2):
        super(CustomModel, self).compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)
        self.another_loss= another_loss
        # gamma weights the impact of another_loss
        self.gamma = gamma

    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self.model(x, training=True)  # Forward pass

            # Compute the loss value
            # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
            ce_loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

            additional_loss = self.another_loss(y, y_pred)
            combined_loss = ce_loss + self.gamma * additional_loss 


        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(combined_loss , trainable_vars)
        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)

        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

    def test_step(self, data):
        x, y = data
        y_pred = self.model(x, training=False)  # Forward pass
        self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        # self.compiled_metrics
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```